# how to generate user defined "404 page not found" in nginx?

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

i have deployed a sample django project with gunicorn on my nginx server, I need to show my own `404 page not found` html page when user enters a wrong url.I tried like this in my `nginx.conf` file

```
server {
listen localhost:8899;
root /home/mulagala/Desktop/projects/28-05-2014/mysite/mysite/templates
access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/example.error.log;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8060;
}

# redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
#
  error_page  404              /404.html;
  location  = /404.html {
    }

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    }


location /static/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias /home/mulagala/Desktop/projects/28-05-2014/mysite/static/;
}
}
```

But when i enter a wrong url still i am getting django default message `Page not found (404)` , and showing all my url's.Am i need to change anything in my django project or anything else.What mistake i am doing.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/proxy_intercept_errors

Comment: Have you created your own 404.html in the templates directory?

Comment: @Josh Yes I have created

Comment: @Mulagala where is your `root` directive? How nginx should know where to look for 404.html?

Comment: @AlexeyTen,Yes i have placed after posting the question, But still same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need this `error_page 404` block and make sure you have `proxy_intercept_errors off;`. If these two conditions are met, nginx will let the application (here, Django) returns its own 404 page.

This configuration file should be fine:

```
server {
    listen localhost:8899;
    root /home/mulagala/Desktop/projects/28-05-2014/mysite/;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8060;
    }

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/mulagala/Desktop/projects/28-05-2014/mysite/static/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where can i find that `proxy_intercept_errors` and i am running my application with `gunicorn`

Comment: @Mulagala By default it is set to `off`. If you have not modified the nginx global configuration it should be fine without.

Comment: I did like you said, If it is handle by django we should place `DEBUG = False` in setting file.If i did like that i am getting `Bad Request (400)`

Comment: @Mixime Lorant,Thank you i had solved my problem by handling `Bad Request 400`.And my 404 page is rendering now

Answer (score 0):

Here's an Nginx config example serving `404` page using `nginx` not `django` itself:

```
upstream faarco {
    server faarco_app:8000;
}

limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=50r/s;

server {
    client_max_body_size 20m;

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://faarco;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;  # note
        error_page 404 /custom_404.html;  # note
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /code/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
          root /code/;
    }

    error_page 404 /custom_404.html;
    location = /custom_404.html {  # note
        root /code/static/error_pages;
        internal;
    }
}
```

Ensure the `/code/static/error_pages/custom_404.html` file and path exist and have `755` permission.